# Gtk.ApplicationWindow cannot be a Parent

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gtk4, gobject-introspection

While porting my App (with modal dialogs) from Gtk(3.0) to Gtk(4.0) I found out that I want to use a `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` instead of a `Gtk.Window`. But now the Dialogs are not modal/they do not accept my `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` as Parent.

As I know `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` is a class based on `Gtk.Window`, so why aren't the Dialog accepting my window?

---

Extra Infos:

```py
Gtk-Version: 4.0
Dialog-Class: Gtk.MessageDialog(
                parent=self.window,
                modal=True,
                destroy_with_parent=True,
                message_type=Gtk.MessageType.ERROR,
                buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.OK,
                text='Access denid')
TypeOf-self.window: Gtk.ApplicationWindow
TypeOf-self: Gtk.Application
Console-Warning: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.